# Seperate Different Sender in Notification MessagingStyle from FCM push notification

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am recently faced some problem regarding to `NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle`. It is a basic chat app that contain multiple direct messaging. **I faced problem where the push notification cannot be seperated based on different incoming `sender`**

I had refer to [How to use MessagingStyle for notifications without caching messages](https://medium.com/@sidorovroman3/android-how-to-use-messagingstyle-for-notifications-without-caching-messages-c414ef2b816c), but most of the `Notification` implementation is deprecated and newer version is `NotificationCompat`.

Here is my current implementation

```
notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorGrey))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(sound)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
             .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))


val sender = Person.Builder()
            .setName(msg.from?.name)
            .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithBitmap(avatar))
            .setImportant(true)
            .build()
                                

// Used to check active notification for stacking up the chat                                
val activeNotification = findActiveNotification(this@FirebaseMessagingService, NOTIF_ID)

if(activeNotification == null) {
    NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(sender)
          .addMessage(msgContent, Date().time, sender)
          .setBuilder(notification)      <-- When different sender comes in, no new category will be created

          notificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, notification.build())

} else {  <-- THIS IS USED TO DISPLAY STACK NOTIFICATION
   // Extract MessagingStyle object from the active notification.
   val activeStyle = extractMessagingStyleFromNotification(activeNotification)

   // Recover builder from the active notification.
   val recoveredBuilder = Notification.Builder.recoverBuilder(this@FirebaseMessagingService, activeNotification)

  // The recoveredBuilder is Notification.Builder whereas the activeStyle is NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.
  // It means you need to recreate the style as Notification.MessagingStyle to make it compatible with the builder.
  val newStyle = Notification.MessagingStyle(sender.name!!)
  newStyle.conversationTitle = activeStyle?.conversationTitle
  activeStyle?.messages?.forEach {
         newStyle.addMessage(Notification.MessagingStyle.Message(it.text, it.timestamp, it.sender))
  }
  newStyle.addMessage(msgContent, Date().time, sender.name)


  // Set the new style to the recovered builder.
  recoveredBuilder.style = newStyle

  // Update the active notification.
  notificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, recoveredBuilder.build())

}

private fun findActiveNotification(context: Context, notificationId: Int): Notification? {
    return (context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager)
       .activeNotifications.find { it.id == notificationId }?.notification
}
```

The current result grouped different sender together as `findActiveNotification` detected that there is an active notification displayed.

[image]

How can I **separate different category of messages for different sender**? Please advise me if I had done any wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself eventually.
The solution is set unique `notification_id` for every sender

```
val sender = Person.Builder()
     .setName(msg.from?.name)
     .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithBitmap(avatar))
     .setImportant(true)
     .build()

val activeNotification = findActiveNotification(this@FirebaseMessagingService, user.notif_id)  <-- setup unique notif_id for every sender

if(activeNotification == null) {
    NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(sender)
        .addMessage(msgContent, Date().time, sender)
        .setBuilder(notification)

    notificationManager.notify(user.notif_id, notification.build())

} else {
      // Extract MessagingStyle object from the active notification.
       val activeStyle = extractMessagingStyleFromNotification(activeNotification)

       // Recover builder from the active notification.
       val recoveredBuilder = Notification.Builder.recoverBuilder(this@FirebaseMessagingService, activeNotification)

      // The recoveredBuilder is Notification.Builder whereas the activeStyle is NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.
     // It means you need to recreate the style as Notification.MessagingStyle to make it compatible with the builder.
     val newStyle = Notification.MessagingStyle(sender.name!!)
     newStyle.conversationTitle = activeStyle?.conversationTitle

     activeStyle?.messages?.forEach {                           
           newStyle.addMessage(Notification.MessagingStyle.Message(it.text, it.timestamp, it.sender))
     }

     newStyle.addMessage(msgContent, Date().time, sender.name)


     // Set the new style to the recovered builder.
     recoveredBuilder.style = newStyle

     // Update the active notification.
     notificationManager.notify(user.notif_id, recoveredBuilder.build())
}
```